# Reset other selects based upon on one select (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The goal here is to make it to where everytime a parent select changes it's value, all children selects get their value reset to default(1st value of empty string).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class TestingSelects extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectOneValue: "",
            selectTwoValue: "",
            selectThreeValue: "",
            selectFourValue: ""
        }
    }
    selectOneOnChangeHandler = (ev) => {
        this.setState({
                        selectOneValue: ev.target.value,
                        selectTwoValue: "",
                        selectThreeValue: "",
                        selectFourValue: ""
                    });
    }

    selectTwoOnChangeHandler = (ev) => {
        this.setState({
                        ...this.state,
                        selectTwoValue: ev.target.value,
                        selectThreeValue: "",
                        selectFourValue: ""
                    });
    }

    selectThreeOnChangeHandler = (ev) => {
        this.setState({
                        ...this.state,
                        selectThreeValue: ev.target.value,
                        selectFourValue: ""
                    });
    }

    selectFourChangeHandler = (ev) => {
        this.setState({...this.state, selectFourValue: ev.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <form>        
                    <div>
                        <select onChange={ev => this.selectOneOnChangeHandler(ev)}>
                            <option value="">Please Select an Option</option>
                            <option value="select1option1">select 1 option 1</option>
                            <option value="select1option2">select 1 option 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    {
                        this.state.selectOneValue === "select1option1" && 
                            <div>
                                <select onChange={ev => this.selectTwoOnChangeHandler(ev)}>
                                    <option value="">Please Select an Option</option>
                                    <option value="select2option1">select 2 option 1</option>
                                    <option value="select2option2">select 2 option 2</option>
                                    <option value="select2option3">select 2 option 3</option>
                                    <option value="select2option4">select 2 option 4</option>
                                    <option value="select2option5">select 2 option 5</option>
                                    <option value="select2option6">select 2 option 6</option>
                                    <option value="select2option7">select 2 option 7</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                    }
                    {
                        (this.state.selectTwoValue === "select2option1" || 
                        this.state.selectTwoValue === "select2option2" || 
                        this.state.selectTwoValue === "select2option5" || 
                        this.state.selectTwoValue === "select2option7") && 
                            <div>
                                <select onChange={ev => this.selectThreeOnChangeHandler(ev)}>
                                    <option value="">Please Select an Option</option>
                                    <option value="select3option1">select 3 option 1</option>
                                    <option value="select3option2same">select 3 option 2</option>
                                    <option value="select3option2same">select 3 option 3</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                    }
                    {
                        this.state.selectThreeValue === "select3option2same" && 
                            <div>
                                <select onChange={ev => this.selectFourOnChangeHandler(ev)}>
                                    <option value="">Please Select an Option</option>
                                    <option value="allowed">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="denied">No</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                    }
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TestingSelects;
```

**Edit:** How to reproduce issue...

- [First Select]: select 1 option 1
- [Second Select]: select 2 option 1
- [Third Select]: select 3 option 1
- [Second Select]: select 2 option 2

  > Here is where the 3rd select should reset to "Please Select an Option"

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything should work as long as you bind the state to the `value` props of each `<select>` element. The reason why your code doesn't work is because you are not binding the `value` of each select to the component's state.

For instance, this is what you should be doing:

```
<select onChange={ev => this.selectOneOnChangeHandler(ev)} value={this.state.selectOneValue}>
```

Comment: Awesome I was missing the value within the select tag and updating it from state. Thank you so much :D

Comment: Also as a note to others who read this: no two or more values should ever be the same within the same select. So where it says `select3option2same`, this solution would provide an issue and only allow you to select the 3rd option (as the 4th one is the same value). I had to change the 4th option to it's own unique value, then change the boolean logic accordingly. (which is the way it should have been written initially).